# Is it possible to query google cache

Tags: search

Is it possible to query Google's cache with a specific date range.

for instance, if i have a url: www.someurl.com/something

I want to be able to see what Google's cache had indexed for that page at or around a given date range, is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, [The Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://stackoverflow.com) stores old versions of pages by date.

You can see Google's current cache for a page by searching `cache:stackoverflow.com`.  As far as I can tell, you can only access the most recent cache of the page.  For older results you'll need to use the Wayback machine or a similar service.